# Sorting dynamic list not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a dynamic list that is populated and sorted:

```
List<dynamic> eventList = new List<object>();

            foreach (Task t in tasks)
            {
                eventList.Add(
               new
               {
                   id = "t" + t.TaskID.ToString(),
                   title = t.TaskTitle,
                   start = ResolveStartDate(StartDate(t.Schedule.DateFrom.Value)),
                   end = ResolveEndDate(StartDate(t.Schedule.DateFrom.Value), t.Schedule.Hours.Value),
                   description = t.TaskDescription,
                   allDay = false,
                   resource = t.Schedule.EmployeID.ToString(),
                   color = ColorConversion.HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(t.Project.Color.Value))
               }
           );
            }

            foreach (Case c in cases)
            {
                eventList.Add(
               new
               {
                   id = "c" + c.CaseID.ToString(),
                   title = c.CaseTitle + "-" + c.Customer.CustomerDescription,
                   start = ResolveStartDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value)),
                   end = ResolveEndDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value), c.Schedule.Hours.Value),
                   description = c.CaseDescription,
                   allDay = false,
                   resource = c.Schedule.EmployeID.ToString(),
                   color = ColorConversion.HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.Color.Value))
               }
           );

            }

            eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title);
```

When I check in debug mode before and after the sort call, the list is not sorted at all, it is in the order added.

When I run it I see nothing is sorted either. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title);
```

You're assuming that `OrderBy` sorts the existing collection. It doesn't. It *returns* a sequence which is ordered. You're ignoring that return value, so the statement is useless.

You probably want:

```
eventList = eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title).ToList();
```

It's not just `OrderBy` which works like this - *all* LINQ sequence operations (`Select`, `Where`, `Join` etc) leave the original collection unchanged, and return a sequence with the appropriately projected, filtered (etc) data.

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` doesn't change the original list. It just creates a new one, with the same elements as the first one, but in a different order.
Try

```
eventList = eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below is just a query:

```
eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title);
```

It means, that it is something like class, struct statement. It only declarates some structure and do nothing more. In order to *instatiate* that query, you must copy it to an array or list as follows:

```
var sortedArray = eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title).ToArray();
```

After that, eventList will be iterated through and elements will be written to an array and stored in sortedArray variable.